# reset screen timeout in android

Tags: android, screen, reset

I'm using the following code to wake the phone's screen:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "XPAND-IT");
wl.acquire();
```

After this code runs, I want to reset the screen timeout to release the wake lock. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you have the following problem:

- The wake lock is acquired
- Some time passes without the user touching the screen
- The wake lock is released
- The screen goes off immediately (or at least too soon) because the screen timeout period started counting when the wake lock was acquired

There's a simple solution for this: Add the flag `PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE` and the timeout is reset when releasing the wake lock.